# Where can I get professional portfolio review? (Can be paid)

Tags: interface-design, critique, portfolio, review

I just started learning graphic design (especially UI). I learn on my own, and that's okay, however I realize that having feedback from a high class professional, from time to time, would be greatly benefitial.

I don't mind paying for such service.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Contact local professionals... and ask.

Answer (score 1):

Joining local design networks (LinkedIn, Facebook, slack, etc..) can offer access to industry professionals who may be willing to review your site.

Adobe offers online portfolios reviews before some of their events. Keep your eyes out for upcoming industry events and sign up for notifications.

Messaging professionals on Dribbble, Behance and other portfolio sites may produce results.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [Dribbble](https://dribbble.com/) there are so many professionals around the world, but it depends on them whether they are willing to share feedback on your design or not